# Reinstall Linux by keeping user accounts

Tags: linux, linux-mint, user-accounts, reinstall

I am going to upgrade Linux Mint 13 to Linux Mint 17.1 on a home computer. I am going to do a fresh upgrade. There are three partitions for `swap`, `/` and `/home`. I will preserve `swap` and `/home`. The partition for `/` will be formatted and Linux Mint 17.1 will be installed there.

There are four users (including me) on this machine. The files and settings will be safe in `/home`.

The question is how can I preserve user accounts (login names and login passwords) for other users? I know the login information is stored in `/etc/passwd`. I can save and restore this file (or information about other three users). So I can link the home folders with correct login names and UIDs.

What about passwords? Is it enough to save and restore `/etc/shadow`?

It is easy for one user systems. I would just restore my user account during the install by choosing the same login name and login password. And it will correctly link with the correct home folder.

Comment: Just be careful not to modify accounts with UIDs less than 1000 (or whatever value your system is set to start numbering user accounts at).

Comment: `It is easy for one user systems. I would just restore my user account during the install by choosing the same login name and login password.` It is not. You will get a new and empty home folder.

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/) link

Comment: @khajvah That’s not true for separate `/home` partitions. Of course it won’t delete existing user folders. At the very worst, the UIDs might not match, but fixing that is trivial.

Comment: @DanielB I meant, empty folder for the particular user not the entire partition.

Comment: @khajvah, I have done it several times for single-user setting. It works because I am always the first user with UID=1000 and I do not change my login name. So I am ending at the same home folder as before reinstall.

Comment: @khajvah, Thanks for the link! Sounds good. I am surprised there is not a tool for that task.

Comment: @djhurio good idea for a new project ;)

Comment: @khajvah, just did the upgrade successfully following the manual you linked here. Make it as an answer and I will accept it.